# MVVM привязать двумерный массив строк к datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Необходимо заполнить dataGrid двумерным массивом строк.
и все бы было просто если бы не паттерн.

выслушаю все предложения
P.S. если в результате реализации можно будет еще и названия header колонок дать будет ваще топ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Советую использовать пакет [`Gu.Wpf.DataGrid2D`](https://github.com/JohanLarsson/Gu.Wpf.DataGrid2D) в котором есть возможность задавать заголовки для столбцов.

Для установки можно использовать NuGet

```
Install-Package Gu.Wpf.DataGrid2D
```

Пример использования

```
xmlns:dataGrid2D="http://gu.se/DataGrid2D"
```

и

```
<DataGrid dataGrid2D:ItemsSource.Array2D="{Binding Data2D}"
          dataGrid2D:ItemsSource.ColumnHeadersSource="{Binding ColumnHeaders}"
          dataGrid2D:ItemsSource.RowHeadersSource="{Binding RowHeaders}" />
```

Comment: но как привязать сам массив я так и не понял

Comment: @AlexandrAlexandr вы перешли по ссылке на гитхаб страницу? там есть примеры

Comment: а проблема там все таже. создать новый массив с новыми размера можно, но на форме он не отобразиться

Comment: @AlexandrAlexandr не уверен,что понимаю в чем возникает проблема. Мы не могли бы продолжить обсуждение поиска решения в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f) ? на мой взгляд так будет намного быстрее, просто сделайте пинг когда у вас будет время.